# Imagemagick - add horizontal rules at variable y coordinates

Tags: imagemagick

I have a color scanned multipage pdf with a table of records, the table is separated into rows and columns but there is only a solid line separating the columns, whereas the rows are separated by an empty row. The columns run through the empty rows as well. Some of the rows are multiple lines of text so the row height varies.

Using ImageMagick I want to insert a black horizontal line in between every row. I figure that the best way to do it is at the y coordinate immediately above the entry number that appears in the left most column, and have that inserted line stretch across the whole width of the image.

Before
[image: before example]

After
[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to draw a line? Or how to determine where to draw it? Or both? What OS do you use? Unless you have more than 100 pages, it would probably be quicker to do it with Photoshop by the time you have developed and tested a script.

Comment: You'll probably want to crop to extract the first column, then use *"Connected Components"* to find the y-coordinate of each number in that column, then draw a line at that position (minus a few pixels) on the original image.

Comment: Average the image to one column and find the large gaps between sections. Then draw lines at those locations.